# Predicting Monthly Brand Sales (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, statistics, linear-regression, forecasting, finance

I'm currently looking at daily sales data of a specific brand over the course of the past year. My objective is to create a formula to roughly estimate the sales growth for future months.
[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6GRx.png) isn't going very well, as the brand is very volatile in monthly sales, making it impossible to predict with a basic linear formula. I'm arriving at the conclusion that a single year's worth of sales isn't enough data, and I may have to result to provide a specific formula depending on the month. Is there anything I haven't thought of?
Note: Recording of sales start on the 15th of every month

Comment: You may need to ask this question over at [math.stackoverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com) or [stats.stackoverflow](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: You can combine the forecast() with a rate of change factor over the last 3 months for example - at least that was what we did when looking at 1, 3 and 6 months in service...

Answer (score 0):

Your sales are showing seasonality.  Consider using sasonal ARIMA models.